# JsonProperty c# Serialize Dictionary values into an array

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, deserialization

I have the following dictionary:

```
   [JsonProperty("Simulations")]
    public IDictionary<int, Simulation> Simulations { get; set; }
```

#### Actual behavior:

When I'm sending my data to the front I send it as an object:

```
   "simulations": {
       "02": {
            "rachatBrut": 542,
            "montantPercu": 250,
            },
        "52": {
            "rachatBrut": 400,
            "montantPercu": 385,
            },
    }
```

#### Wanted Behavior

I want to send only the values of the dictionary as an array:

```
   "simulations": [
       {
            "rachatBrut": 542,
            "montantPercu": 250,
       },
       {
            "rachatBrut": 400,
            "montantPercu": 385,
       }
    ]
```

Comment: `JsonIgnore` the existing property. Create a new readonly property which projects the array you want in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either add another property and use [JsonIgnore] on the one u have right now. To make the new one an array just call .ToArray() on the Dictionary.
Or you can write yourself an own [CustomJsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for this behavior.

For your specific case this would produce an array like the one u need:

```
Simulations.Select(k => k.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: It produces an array containing KeyValuePair Objects. If u want only the values u need to use a Select before.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up converting my dictionary into an array of simulations